# how to implement Marquee in Oracle adf?

Tags: oracle-adf, marquee

How to use marquee tag in Oracle adf (version 12c - 12.2.1.3.0)? or some feature to scroll some message (Message should be picked from database) from right to left.

The below code worked in 11g, but after migrating to 12c message is not scrolling.

< marquee>< af:outputText id="ot1" value="#{pageFlowScope.MyBean.userMessage}"/>< /marquee>

I have tried the below oracle recommendation, even it is not working.

< af:outputText inlineStyle="height=100%" id="prdc2" escape="false" value="< marquee bgcolor=orange height=20 direction=right behavior=alternate scrollDelay='200' id='rates' dataFormatAs='text' behavior='alternate'>#{bindings.rateText}< /marquee>"/>

Link for recommendation: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/1140463_1.html

Comment: The below is working fine for me, but it is showing error (Marquee can not be nested inside an Verbatim element.) in the jsf page.
<f:verbatim><marquee>#{pageFlowScope.MyBean.userMessage}</marquee></f:verbatim>

Answer (score 0):

```
<marquee direction ="left" onmouseover="this.stop();"
onmouseout="this.start();" scrolldelay="120">
<af:outputFormatted id="marquee_text"
value="Welcome to ADF. Any warnings will be updated here. "                                                
inlineStyle="color:Red; font-weight:bold;"/>
</marquee>
```

use this code inside the af form it worked for me